# PHP server side validation of future date in comparison with today's date

Tags: php, validation, date, datetime

My database has a column, for example, named

`expected_event_date` data type of which is set to `timestamp` and it's attribute is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Users input expected future event date through a form.

How shall I validate the future date in comparison with current date in this case? The server should omit an error in case users input past date.

I'm looking for something like,

```
$error = "invalid date" 
if ($_POST['expected_event_date'] < today's date only but not time ) {
echo $error;    
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: jsut use time() function which return current date in timestamp

Comment: you need to explain what format those values are in. Is it some goofy string like `April 5th, 2070`? If so, that's just a string, and doing `'April 5th, 2070' < 'May 2nd, 2014'` is going to be **TRUE**, because `A` comes before `M`.

Comment: What format is the date the user is entering in?

Comment: @Marc B & MikeyBunny format is default `timestamp` `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Comment: @ekans , time() can't validate it. It returns invalid date in all circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function for you :)

```
$error = "invalid date" 
if ($this->isValidDate($_POST['expected_event_date'],'Y-m-d')) {
echo $error;    
}

public function isValidDate($date,$dateFormat){

    $date = trim($date);
    $time = strtotime($date);

    if(date($dateFormat, $time) < date('Y-m-d')){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! @Burhan Çetin that's perfect! I couldn't write a function like this at this stage.